# UIView internal constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I have created a simple UIView that contains a red box (UIImage) at its centre.  When all the constraints are constants the code works fine.  However, if I replace the height constraint with one that makes the box half the height of the view then the box disappears.

I assume that this is either because I am doing it wrong (obviously) or I need to do something more to force the constraint to realise the UIView height is greater than zero.

How do I set the redBox height constraint so that it is always half the height of the BoxView?

```
import UIKit

class BoxView: UIView {

    public var redBox: UIImageView

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        redBox = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        redBox.backgroundColor = .red

        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .yellow

        addSubview(redBox)
        redBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let margins = layoutMarginsGuide
        redBox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        redBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        redBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
      //redBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        redBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, constant: 0.5)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view = BoxView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
redBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, constant: 0.5)
```

with

```
redBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

---

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    redBox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
    redBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
    redBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    redBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
])
```

In your current code first you miss the `.isActive = true` which has the same effect as if the line doesn't exist , and if specified this will make the box height equal to the view's height + constant ( = 0.5 )

> box height = view height * multiplier + constant

and since default multiplier = 1 and you set constant = 0.5 this will be

> box height = view height * 1.0 + 0.5

But instead you need

> box height = view height * 0.5 + 0 // omit consatnt in constraint and it will be zero

---

```
class BoxView: UIView { 
    public var redBox: UIImageView
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        redBox = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        redBox.backgroundColor = .red
        self.backgroundColor = .yellow
        addSubview(redBox)
        redBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let margins = layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            redBox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            redBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            redBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            redBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
        ])
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paulw11 will do

Comment: No need.  I understand the difference but didn't spot the error.  (Two silly errors in one line.)